# Obtain values separated by hyphens

Tags: r, stata

I have a bunch of values in a dataset that are formulated like `2000-3222` and `10/1-10`.

I would like to split these so that it lists `2000`, `2001` etc. and  `10/1`, `10/2` etc., all in their own rows.

Is there any command to do this in Stata or R?

---

**EDIT:**

Example data:

```
input int SRNo str200 SchemeName str30 CTSNo1 str4 CTSNo2
69 "Khimji Nagar SRA Co-op.Housing Society Ltd." "467" ""
70 "Jai Bhavani CHS Ltd. (Proposed)" "7 (Pt.)" ""
71 "Shivshakti SRA CHS Ltd." "364 ‘A’" ""
72 "Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)" "96 (Pt.) -99(Pt.)" ""
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example data (in which I added a few more observations to make things more illustrative), you need something along the following lines:

```
clear

input int SRNo str200 SchemeName str30 CTSNo1 str4 CTSNo2
69 "Khimji Nagar SRA Co-op.Housing Society Ltd." "467" ""
70 "Jai Bhavani CHS Ltd. (Proposed)" "7 (Pt.)" ""
71 "Bhavani Housing" "12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)" ""
72 "Shivshakti SRA CHS Ltd." "364 ‘A’" ""
73 "Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)" "96 (Pt.)- 99(Pt.)" ""
74 "Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)" "107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)" ""
end

generate tag = 0
replace tag = 1 if strmatch(CTSNo1, "*-*")

keep if tag == 1
generate part1 = regexs(0) if regexm(CTSNo1, "([0-9]+)")
generate part2 = substr(regexs(0), 2, .) if regexm(CTSNo1, "-.*([0-9])")

local obs = _N

forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
       local xpa = abs(real(part1[`i']) - real(part2[`i'])) + 1
       expand `xpa' if _n == `i'        
}

bysort SRNo (CTSNo1): egen interim = seq()
bysort SRNo (CTSNo1): generate NCTSNo1 = real(part1) + interim - 1

drop tag part1 part2 interim
order SRNo SchemeName CTSNo1 NCTSNo1 CTSNo2
```

The above code snipped produces the desired results:

```
list

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | SRNo                   SchemeName                 CTSNo1   NCTSNo1   CTSNo2 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        12          |
  2. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        13          |
  3. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        14          |
  4. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        15          |
  5. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        16          |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        17          |
  7. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        18          |
  8. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        19          |
  9. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        20          |
 10. |   71              Bhavani Housing        12(Pt.)-21(Pt.)        21          |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |   73   Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)      96 (Pt.)- 99(Pt.)        96          |
 12. |   73   Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)      96 (Pt.)- 99(Pt.)        97          |
 13. |   73   Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)      96 (Pt.)- 99(Pt.)        98          |
 14. |   73   Shree Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)      96 (Pt.)- 99(Pt.)        99          |
 15. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       107          |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       108          |
 17. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       109          |
 18. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       110          |
 19. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       111          |
 20. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       112          |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 21. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       113          |
 22. |   74         Ram CHS Ltd. (Prop.)   107 (Pt.)- 114 (Pt.)       114          |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

The `forvalues` loop in my solution above is not necessary. A different way of doing this, which avoids looping over observations, is the following:

```
bysort SRNo (CTSNo1): generate xpa = abs(real(part1) - real(part2)) + 1 
expand xpa
```

Comment: than you so much for this. If I have CTSNo variables up to 54 (CTSNo1, CTSNo2, ... CTSNo54), do I need to do this individually for each variable?

Comment: Yes, but you can automate the process. For example, you can create a loop to run the code to `generate` one variable at the time and `save` the new variable in a new dataset. After this is done you can `merge` all the datasets in one containing all variables.

Comment: sorry but I'm fairly new to Stata. Could you provide an example of the loop for the CTSNo's in the code?

Comment: I think it would be best to start a new separate question for this, as the posts here are already long.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all values look like your example and you variable(s) is of type string:

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. 
. generate string1 = "2000-3222"

. generate new_string1 = substr(string1, 1, 4)

. 
. generate string2 = "10/1-10"

. generate new_string2 = substr(string2, 1, 4)

. 
. list

     +-------------------------------------------+
     |   string1   new_st~1   string2   new_st~2 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2000-3222       2000   10/1-10       10/1 |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

This solution is useful if you only need a certain part of the original variable.

---

**EDIT:**

Using @Nick's excellent suggestion:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate string1 = "2000-3222"
generate string2 = "10/1-10"

split string1, parse("-") generate(split_string1)
split string2, parse("/") generate(split_string2)

list

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
     |   string1   string2   split~11   split~12   split~21   split~22 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2000-3222   10/1-10       2000       3222         10       1-10 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, this solution will give you two variables for `string1` and another two for `string2` each containing both (separate) parts of the original variable.

Comment: See also `split`.

Comment: @pearlyspencer Thank you for this. I'm a little confused about how to post my code using dataex, but my data is a list of projects and each project has a few points associated with it. I have separated these in Excel already using comma-delimited text to columns. My end goal is to reshape long to turn these columns into rows, but right now some of the rows have a range of numbers, like 96-99. Is there code that I can use to expand all numbers and strings separated by hyphens at the same time? There are a lot. Sorry if this is confusing, but thank you for your time.

Comment: @BrynneGodfrey I edited my post to include Nick's more general solution. Unfortunately without seeing your data we cannot advise further.

Comment: @BrynneGodfrey When you run `dataex` in Stata it will generate some output, which you can then copy and paste here. To do so, click 'edit' underneath your question and paste the code.

Comment: @PearlySpencer sorry for the delay, but I added a few example rows. For example, I would like 96-99 to be 96, 97, 98, 99, all in their own row but for the same project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrynneGodfrey What you want is programmable but cannot be done with a single command. Will try to work something out.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Do you happen to know of a way to do this in R, or think that it would be easier?

Comment: I do not use R but will re-tag the question so others may provide a solution there.

Comment: See my new answer for a solution based on your example data.